# What decibel range would be considered a "quiet" range hood?

Tags: kitchens, hood

I would like to buy a quiet range hood. Can someone please tell me how many decibels I should look for?

Comment: I edited the question to keep it on topic.

Answer (score 1):

From Lowes.com:

"Range Hood Sound Levels

The sound that a range hood makes is measured in sone. One sone is roughly equal to the sound of a refrigerator running. Normal conversations take place at about 4 sones, and light traffic rates up to around 8. Use sones to compare units, but be aware that the higher the CFM, the higher the sone rating is likely to be. Look for normal sone ratings to find the quietest hood at normal operation levels."

Not all online sources publish sone specifications, but you'll often find that number on the actual packaging.

Comment: I don't know why manufacturers use the unusual "sone" unite for exhaust fans but it does seem to be common. Virtually every other appliance (and other industries) measure noise with dBA decibels.

Answer (score 0):

Sue, if this idea is not too late: Consider the exhaust fans location. Those small ceiling fans you see at the big box stores can only be installed in the room you want to vent and will quickly (due to use) become noisier. Consider a whole house or multi-room exhaust fan unit. Basically, it's a larger exhaust fan that is installed anyplace in your attic. The motor is located away from the room. Only the duct line is extends to the ceiling register.